# В Старом Крыму или Старом Крыме?

Tags: склонение

Я уверена, что «в Старом Крыму», никак не «Крыме»...

Answer (score 3):

Литературная норма:
о Крыме, в Крыму (*где? в каком месте?* местный падеж); **в Старом Крыму**.

Можно посмотреть статистику Нацкорпуса:
[в Крыму](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%83) (2682); [в Крыме](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B5) (3 — только XIX век).

Можно ознакомиться с мнением "Грамоты": [в Крыму](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%83#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%3A%20%D0%BE%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%83.&text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%A3%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%95%3F&text=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%83.).